# high throughput way of "increment" numerical value operation

Tags: ignite

I have a distributed cache of float (not int). My process will frequently increment these floats and access them occasionally.

If it's local, atomic float data structure (or float adder if there is one) with an increment method would probably be the best way to go. Non-blocking and async would be ideal, since the sequence of increment does not matter as long as each increment is conducted eventually.

What's the best way of incrementing numerical value to achieve high throughput?

My current method is:

1. batch several increment operations for different key
2. using [`invokeAll`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#invokeAll-java.util.Map-java.lang.Object...-) method in `IgniteCache`, passing in a `CacheEntryProcessor` which contains the increment value for each key.
3. `CacheAtomicityMode` configuration is set to `ATOMIC`

Is this the best way to go?

Is there any configuration that I should pay attention to for performance boost, e.g. use binary format or on-heap memory or avoid unnecessary serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are definitely on the right track.

Binary format will be used by default, so you do not need any special configuration for it. I do not think you should worry about serialization of floats, so I would not configure an on-heap cache, unless you run into performance issues.

I also would suggest to take a look at internal implementation of  [IgniteAtomicSequence](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteAtomicLong.html) as it may give you more useful ideas.

Lastly, I would suggest to implement it as [Ignite service](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid), which will allow you to provide a custom API tailored for this functionality.

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, thanks a lot for your answering! I am currently implementing the functionality using CompteTask, locally deployed to each note in the cluster, so that each node can make the increment call (and some work to calculate the increment). I went through the docs but wondering how does IgniteCompute differs from IgniteService API in design use case?

Comment: @Hao Ignite service will just provide a public API you expose for this functionality. Internally, inside of the service, you should feel free to use any Ignite API, including compute, caching, data, etc... You can also use compute API without wrapping it into a service.